# insert using subqueries that return a different number of values

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, insert, multiple-columns

Using Postgres, I'm trying to insert into table "sellable_product_categories" ids coming from two different tables (sellables & product_categories).

The first table has multiple values while the second only has one (the id of the product category).

```
insert into sellable_product_categories (sellable_id, product_category_id)
values (
        (select id from sellables where category = 'Backsplash'),
        (select id from product_categories where name = 'Tile'));
```

The code generates this error: `"ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"` which makes sense since the insert is asymmetrical, but how to resolve this?

The desired result would be something like this:

| id | sellable_id | product_category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 17 | 8 |
| 2 | 20 | 8 |
| 3 | 35 | 8 |
| 4 | 64 | 8 |
| 5 | 89 | 8 |
| 6 | 92 | 8 |

I tried many different permutations, including a left join, but at this point I'm just flat out stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert the appropriate values directly from a query where you match up the sellables and the product category as required. It appears from your question that you want a cross join on a subset of rows from each table, which can be done like so:

```
INSERT INTO sellable_product_categories (sellable_id, product_category_id)
    SELECT s.id, p.id
    FROM sellables s
    CROSS JOIN product_categories p 
    WHERE s.category = 'Backsplash'
      AND p.name = 'Tile'
```

Comment: Patrick, thank you! That solved the issue for me. I'd completely forgotten about cross joins, glad I asked. Again, thank you for taking the time to answer.

Hope this helps others in the future. :)